# ASP.NET Core: Custom IFileProvider prevents default IFileProvider from working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to serve some JavaScript from embedded resources in a class library. I managed to find out about the `IFileProvider` and created my own which is now working well. However, the problem I have now is that physical static files (from **wwwroot**) are no longer found.

I have the following in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(
   new StaticFileOptions()
   {
       // Override file provider to allow embedded resources
       FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
           HostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider,
           new EmbeddedScriptFileProvider()),

       //etc
   });
```

I would have assumed using the `CompositeFileProvider` would mean that if the file is not found in one of the file providers, then it will try the other. I am also assuming that the default file provider is the one I specified as `HostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider`. Is this incorrect?

The only other thing I can think of is that the problem is coming from inside my provider itself in the `GetFileInfo()` method. The definition of which is as follows:

```
public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subpath))
    {
        return new NotFoundFileInfo(subpath);
    }

    if (subpath.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        subpath = subpath.Substring(1);
    }

    var metadata = EmbeddedScripts.FindEmbeddedResource(subpath);

    if (metadata == null)
    {
        return new NotFoundFileInfo(subpath);
    }

    return new EmbeddedResourceFileInfo(metadata);
}
```

Could it be that returning `NotFoundFileInfo(subpath)` is causing my problems for physical css, js and other static files? If so, what should I be returning here instead so that the system knows to use the other file provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK after a little digging in the source code (isn't it great that .NET is now open source?!), I managed to find the following links were very helpful indeed:

[CompositeFileProvider.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite/CompositeFileProvider.cs)
- Based on the implementation in `GetFileInfo()`, I can see that I should pass back `null` instead of `NotFoundFileInfo(subpath)` if I want the other providers to try resolve it.

[StaticFileMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/StaticFileMiddleware.cs)
- This file shows that if the `FileProvider` is not specified (`null`) when setting up static file configuration with `app.UseStaticFiles`, then it will resolve one with the following line of code:

`_fileProvider = _options.FileProvider ?? Helpers.ResolveFileProvider(hostingEnv);`

And looking at [Helpers.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/Helpers.cs) shows the following code:

```
internal static IFileProvider ResolveFileProvider(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv)
{
    if (hostingEnv.WebRootFileProvider == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing FileProvider.");
    }
    return hostingEnv.WebRootFileProvider;
}
```

Therefore, my assumption of using `HostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider` was incorrect. I should be using `HostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` instead.

Everything now works as it should.